# Spalsh Screen shows battery status on top

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to hide the top bar from splash screens [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbenS.png):[First image]  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sba7K.png):[Second Image] as you can see these are two splash screens sample and i want to hide the upper bar which shows battery status and other things on image2,which is also shown in my app

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your Manifest file under the Splashscreen activity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

When u use AppCompat you have to include below line of code in your style to get the FullScreen.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```